# sorting even and odd numbers in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Im trying to write a function that takes a random list and sorts it (in c) so that even numbers are first, doing so without creating a second list.
What im trying to do is moving a newly found even number to the head of the list (making the previous head the seconnd element).
Cant understand why my pointers get messed up though -

```
typedef struct node node;
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    node *next;
};

void sortlist(node *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("Empty list \n");
    }
    node *index1 = head->next;
    node *oldhead;
    if (index1 == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    while (index1 != NULL) {
        if (index1->data % 2 == 0) {
            oldhead = head;
            head = index1;
            head->next = oldhead;
        }
        index1 = index1->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you removing the even list element before adding them to head?

Comment: @WasiAhmad where?

Comment: In the while loop section. I have added a tentative solution, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Main idea**: Suppose you have a list as below.

1->3->2->4

When you want to make the element `2` the new head, you have to do two things.

- Unlink element `2` and make next element of `3` to `4`. [which you are missing in your code]
- Make a new node and make it the new head of the list.

Then the list will look like `2->1->3->4`. Again doing the same thing for element `4`, it will look like `4->2->1->3`.

So, I believe you need (tentatively) something like this.

```
void sortlist(node *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("Empty list \n");
    }
    node *current = head->next;
    node *previous = head;
    while(current != NULL){
        if(current->data % 2 == 0){
            previous->next = current->next;
            current->next = head;
            head = current;
        } else{
            previous = previous->next;
            //previous = current; [an equivalent statement]
        }
        current = previous->next;
    }
}
```

An alternative approach if you want to create a new node and make it the head of the list.

```
void sortlist(node *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("Empty list \n");
    }
    node *current = head->next;
    node *previous = head;
    while(current != NULL){
        if(current->data % 2 == 0){
            previous->next = current->next;
            node* new_node = (struct node*) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
            new_node->data = current->data;
            new_node->next = head;
            head = new_node;
        } else{
            previous = previous->next;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

**Update**: I have verified both the code snippet. Its working!

Comment: I see now, Thanks!
How would you sort it otherwise (in a way that wouldnt be weird), without creating another list?

Comment: I said weird because i doubt that your code will sort the list. Why don't you use any sorting algorithm, say bubble sort or merge sort or insertion sort?

Answer (score 0):

This is not enough: when you move a node to the head, you need also to direct its *previous* to its *next*. Since your list is linked in only one direction, you need to keep track of what was its previous.

Moreover, sending the head pointer like this, **by value**, will not change it in the caller, so the caller will loose track of the head of the list. Therefore, you need to pass the head pointer in a way that it can be modified and retrieved, that is, send a pointer to that pointer:

```
void sortlist(node** head) {
    if (*head == NULL) {
        printf("Empty list \n");
    }
    node *index1 = (*head)->next;
    node *prev = *head;

    while (index1 != NULL) {
        if (index1->data % 2 == 0) {
            prev->next = index1->next;
            index1->next = *head;
            *head = index1;
        }
        else {
            prev = index1;
        }
        index1 = prev->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you skip the head itself and start with head->next.

Also the head node should be passed by reference because the head is changed in the function.

And it does not make sense to output a message that the list empty because the caller can check itself before calling the function whether the list is empty can not it?

The function can look the following way

```
void sortlist(node **head)
{
    for (node **current = head; *current != NULL; )
    {
        if ((*current)->data % 2 == 0 && current != head)
        {
            node *tmp = *current;
            *current = (*current)->next;
            tmp->next = *head;
            *head = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            current = &(*current)->next;
        }
    }
}
```

For example if the list contains the following clause

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

then after calling the function it will look like

```
8 6 4 2 0 1 3 5 7 9
```